# ABAP feature lists

Tags: release, abap

So I just discovered [String templates](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/abenstring_templates.htm) and they are amazing.
Is there a resource where I can find what each SAP release brings to ABAP ?

Not strictly an SO question, but it will make all ABAP developers better if they can study what is new in the releases.

Comment: Just be aware that code with too many string templates tends to result in write-only code - just like regular expressions...

Comment: Agreed, I plan to only use the { var } parts to avoid CONCATENATE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transaction `ABAPDOCU`, then navigate to ABAP Keyword Documentation --> ABAP - Release-Specific Changes:

[image]